# lwjgl 3 engine does not show anything

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

Im coding a Game with lwjgl3. I initially used lwjgl 2. but of major chanllenges, i switched to lwjgl3.

I walked through a couple tutorials and put together a gameloop with a window class and tried to implement the code i already had.

I had to change multiple things, had challenges like the slick util textureloader, but now im stuck:

Basically what i see is the Window, but nothing is displayed on it.
My Engine is fairly big by now, but i will try to implement the important methods. When you need more, i can post more.

I will post the Shaderfiles for entity and skybox (what im trying to display currently) too

And all i see is a Window with nothing displayed

MAIN CLASS

```
     package main;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;

import entities.Camera;
import entities.Light;
import entities.Player;
import graphics.Window;
import graphics.models.RawModel;
import graphics.models.TexturedModel;
import graphics.renderEngine.Loader;
import graphics.renderEngine.MasterRenderer;
import graphics.renderEngine.OBJLoader;
import graphics.textures.ModelTexture;
import toolbox.Vector3f;


public class Main 
{

    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);

    private Window window;
    private MasterRenderer renderer;
    private Loader loader;

    private int Width;
    private int Height;
    private boolean running = false;
    private double delta;

    List<Light> lights = new ArrayList<Light>();
    Camera camera = null;
    private Player player;
    public Main()
    {


        init();

    }

    private void input()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        if(window.shouldClose()) stop();
    }

    private void update()
    {
        renderer.setHeight(Height);
        renderer.setWidth(Width);
        renderer.setDelta(delta);
    }

    private  void render()
    {
        renderer.processEntity(player);
        renderer.render(lights, camera);
        window.render();
    }

    private void run()
    {

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime = lastTime;
        long diff = 0;

        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        double ns = 1000000000 / 60.0;
        delta = 0.0;

        double dfps = 1000000000 / 60.0;
        double d = 0.0;

        int fps = 0;
        int ups = 0;

        while(running)
        {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            diff = currentTime - lastTime;
            delta += (diff)/ ns;
            d += diff/dfps;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            while(delta >= 1.0)
            {
                input();
                update();
                ups++;
                delta--;
            }

            if(d >- 1.0)
            {
                render();
                fps++;
                d = 0.0;
            }

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() > timer + 1000)
            {
                window.setTitle("Junker.5 | ups: "+ups+"| fps: "+fps+"");
                ups = 0;
                fps = 0;
                timer += 1000;
            }
        }

        cleanUp();
    }



    public void start()
    {
        if(running) return;
        running = true;
        run();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        if(!running) return;
        running = false;
    }


    private void init()
    {

        Width = 1280;
        Height = 720;
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
        glfwInit();



        window = new Window(Width, Height, "Junker.5");
        GL.createCapabilities();

        loader = new Loader();
        renderer = new MasterRenderer(loader);
        renderer.setHeight(Height);
        renderer.setWidth(Width);
        renderer.setDelta(delta);


        RawModel playerShip = OBJLoader.loadObjModel("Puddle Jumper", loader);
        TexturedModel playership = new TexturedModel(playerShip, ModelTexture.loadTexture("white"));

        player = new Player(playership, new Vector3f(0, 0, -50),0,0,0,1);

        lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(0,1000,-5000), new Vector3f(0f,0.4f,5f)));
        lights.add(new Light(new Vector3f(0,0,-10), new Vector3f(1,0,1), new Vector3f(1, 0.01f, 0.002f)));

        try 
        {
            camera = new Camera(player);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cleanUp()
    {
        window.hide();
        //guiRenderer.cleanUp();
        renderer.cleanUp();
        loader.cleanUp();
        window.dispose();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.start();

    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return window.getWidth();
    }

    public int getheight()
    {
        return window.getHeight();
    }

    public double getDelta()
    {
        return delta;
    }

}
```

MASTER RENDERER CLASS

```
    package graphics.renderEngine;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;


import entities.Camera;
import entities.Entity;
import entities.Light;
import entities.Player;
import graphics.models.RawModel;
import graphics.models.TexturedModel;
import graphics.shaders.StaticShader;
import graphics.shaders.TerrainShader;
import graphics.skybox.SkyboxRenderer;
import graphics.terrains.Terrain;
import graphics.textures.ModelTexture;
import toolbox.Matrix4f;
import toolbox.Vector3f;

public class MasterRenderer 
{
    private static final float FOV = 70;
    private static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.01f;
    private static final float FAR_PLANE = 1000;

    public int Width;
    public double delta;
    public int Height;

    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;

    private StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
    private TerrainRenderer terrainRenderer;
    private TerrainShader terrainShader = new TerrainShader();

    private EntityRenderer renderer;

    private Map<TexturedModel, List<Entity>> entities = new HashMap<TexturedModel, List<Entity>>();
    private List<Terrain> terrains = new ArrayList<Terrain>();

    private SkyboxRenderer skyboxRenderer ;

    public MasterRenderer(Loader loader)
    {
        enableCulling();

        createProjectionMatrix();
        renderer = new EntityRenderer(shader, projectionMatrix);
        terrainRenderer = new TerrainRenderer(terrainShader, projectionMatrix);
        skyboxRenderer = new SkyboxRenderer(loader, projectionMatrix);


    }

    public static void enableCulling()
    {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
    }

    public static void disableCullig()
    {
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    public void render(List<Light> lights, Camera camera)
    {
        prepare();
        shader.start();
        shader.loadLights(lights);
        shader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
        renderer.render(entities);
        shader.stop();
        terrainShader.start();
        terrainShader.loadLights(lights);
        terrainShader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
        terrainRenderer.render(terrains);
        terrainShader.stop();
        skyboxRenderer.render(camera);
        terrains.clear();
        entities.clear();
    }

    public void processTerrain(Terrain terrain)
    {
        terrains.add(terrain);
    }

    public void processEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        TexturedModel entityModel = entity.getModel();
        List<Entity> batch = entities.get(entityModel);
        if(batch != null)
        {
            batch.add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            List<Entity> newBatch = new ArrayList<Entity>();
            newBatch.add(entity);
            entities.put(entityModel, newBatch);
        }
    }

    private void createProjectionMatrix()
    {
        float aspectRatio = (float) Width / (float) Height;
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;   
    }

    public void prepare()
    {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glClearColor(0.03f, 0f, 0.0f, 1);
    }

    public void cleanUp()
    {
        shader.cleanUp();
        terrainShader.cleanUp();
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) 
    {
        Width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) 
    {
        Height = height;
    }

    public void setDelta(double delta) 
    {
        this.delta = delta;
    }
}
```

STATIC SHADER CLASS

```
 package graphics.shaders;

import java.util.List;

import entities.Camera;
import entities.Light;
import toolbox.Maths;
import toolbox.Matrix4f;
import toolbox.Vector3f;



public class StaticShader extends ShaderProgram
{

    public static final String VERTEX_FILE = "./Ressources/Shaders/VertexShader.shd";
    public static final String FRAGMENT_FILE = "./Ressources/Shaders/FragmentShader.shd";
    public static final int MAX_LIGHTS = 4;

    private int location_transformationMatrix;
    private int location_projectionMatrix;
    private int location_viewMatrix;
    private int location_lightPosition[];
    private int location_lightColour[];
    private int location_attenuation[];
    private int location_shineDamper;
    private int location_reflectivity;
    private int location_useFakeLighting;

    public StaticShader() 
    {
        super(VERTEX_FILE, FRAGMENT_FILE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindAttributes() 
    {
        super.bindAttribute(0, "position");
        super.bindAttribute(1, "textureCoords");
        super.bindAttribute(2, "normal");
    }

    protected void getAllUniformLocations()
    {
        location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
        location_projectionMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
        location_viewMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("viewMatrix");
        location_shineDamper = super.getUniformLocation("shineDamper");
        location_reflectivity = super.getUniformLocation("reflectivity");
        location_useFakeLighting = super.getUniformLocation("useFakeLighting");


        location_lightPosition = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        location_attenuation = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        location_lightColour = new int[MAX_LIGHTS];
        for(int i = 0;i<MAX_LIGHTS;i++)
        {
            location_lightPosition[i] = super.getUniformLocation("lightPosition["+i+"]");
            location_lightColour[i] = super.getUniformLocation("lightColour["+i+"]");   
            location_attenuation[i] = super.getUniformLocation("attenuation["+i+"]");   
        }
    }

    public void loadFakeLightingVariable(boolean useFake)
    {
        super.loadBoolean(location_useFakeLighting, useFake);
    }

    public void loadShineVariables(float damper, float reflectivity)
    {
        super.LoadFloat(location_shineDamper, damper);
        super.LoadFloat(location_reflectivity, reflectivity);
    }

    public void loadTreansformationMatrix(Matrix4f matrix)
    {
        super.loadMatrix(location_transformationMatrix, matrix);
    }

    public void loadLights(List<Light> lights)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<MAX_LIGHTS;i++)
        {
            if(i<lights.size())
            {
                super.LoadVector(location_lightPosition[i], lights.get(i).getPosition());
                super.LoadVector(location_lightColour[i], lights.get(i).getColour());
                super.LoadVector(location_attenuation[i], lights.get(i).getAttenuation());
            }
            else
            {
                super.LoadVector(location_lightPosition[i], new Vector3f(0,0,0));
                super.LoadVector(location_lightColour[i], new Vector3f(0,0,0));
                super.LoadVector(location_attenuation[i], new Vector3f(1,0,0));
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadViewMatrix(Camera camera)
    {
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = Maths.createViewMatrix(camera);
        super.loadMatrix(location_viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    }

    public void loadProjectionMatrix(Matrix4f projection)
    {
        super.loadMatrix(location_projectionMatrix, projection);
    }

}
```

SHADERFILES:

FRAGMENT SHADER

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector[4];
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec3 lightColour[4];
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;
uniform vec3 attenuation[4];

void main(void)
{
    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);

    vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
    float distance = length(toLightVector[i]);
    float attFactor = attenuation[i].x + (attenuation[i].y * distance) + (attenuation[i].z * distance * distance);
        vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector[i]);
        float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
        float brightness = max(nDot1,0.0);
        vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
        vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection,unitNormal);
        float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
        specularFactor = max(specularFactor,0.0);
        float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor,shineDamper);
        totalSpecular = totalSpecular + (dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour[i])/attFactor;
        totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse  + (brightness * lightColour[i])/attFactor;

    }

    totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse, 0.2);

    vec4 textureColour = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
    if(textureColour.a<0.5)
    {
        discard;
    }

    out_Color = vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords) + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
}
```

VERTEX SHADER

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;


out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector[4];
out vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition[4];

uniform float useFakeLighting;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    vec3 actualNormal = normal;
    if(useFakeLighting > 0.5)
    {
        actualNormal = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    }

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(actualNormal,0.0)).xyz;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        toLightVector[i] = lightPosition[i] - worldPosition.xyz;
    }
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

}
```

I have absolutely no idea what im doing wrong. If anyone wants to really help me more personal on this problem, feel free to contact me too.

Thank you soo much!

**EDIT:**

Yes, the Clearcolor works, thats part of why i am confused.
And before i worked ofer my lwjgl2 code to my new lwjgl3 code, the lwjgl3 window DID display simple graphics such as a 3d cube

Here is my window class

WINDOW

```
package graphics;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;


public class Window 
{

    private long window;
    private int Width;
    private int Height;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title)
    {

        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL11.GL_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL11.GL_TRUE);
        //DECORATION
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GL11.GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FOCUSED, GL11.GL_TRUE);
        window = glfwCreateWindow(Width,Height,"Junker.5",NULL,NULL);

        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                 (vidmode.width() - width) / 2,
                (vidmode.height() - height) / 2
            ); 

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    }

    public void dispose()
    {
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    }

    public void hide()
    {
        glfwHideWindow(window);
    }

    public void render()
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    public void show()
    {
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        glfwSetWindowTitle(window, title);
    }

    public boolean shouldClose() 
    {
          if(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
          {
           return false;
          }
          else
          {
              return true;
          }
    }



    public int getWidth() 
    {
        return Width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) 
    {
        Width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() 
    {
        return Height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) 
    {
        Height = height;
    }

    public void changecursor()
    {
        // Create the cursor object
        //long cursor = GLFW.glfwCreateCursor(imageBuffer, 0, 0);

        /*if (cursor == MemoryUtil.NULL)
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating cursor");

        // Set the cursor on a window
        GLFW.glfwSetCursor(window, cursor);*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Copy pasting a tutorial is never a good idea. You end up having no clue about your "own" engine and posting hundreds of lines of code here. Anyway, I see it should draw entities a terrain lights and skybox. Is your screen are cleaned with your clearcolor at least?

Comment: I'd like to see your Window class and to reduce the amount of code you can surely delete ModelTexture class.

Comment: I edited my post with the info you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to fix the problem myself, atleast its displaying stuff now :)

I just hardcoded the Width and height right now. The method of doing a setHeight() in the Main class must have angried the gods of my createProjectionMatrix() function. However, id would be awesome to know how to do this dynamic for future purposes